# why we can create null (empty) node or multi label node in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, null, label, nodes

In Neo4j we can create Null (Empty) and multi label Nodes.

```
CREATE () // Create Empty Node

CREATE (:l1 :l2) // CREATE multi Label Node
```

Why it allow create null (empty) node? what is the benefit and usability of null node? why we need multi label node?

Answer (score 2):

`Node` is the most basic entity in neo4j, which stores data. `Labels` provide a way to group the nodes into sets and they help in fast lookups.

The statement: `CREATE ()` creates a node with no labels and properties, but now to query this node.

`MATCH (n) WHERE labels(n) = 0 return n`,

Neo4j will have to perform all nodes scan. This is inefficient and this is where labels help you.

The statement `CREATE (:l1 :l2)` creates a node with two labels `l1` and `l2`.This node can be easily queried using the queries:

`MATCH (n:l1) return n`

OR

`MATCH (n:l2) return n`

In these queries, neo4j only looks for the nodes grouped under these labels, which helps in faster lookups, since the dataset to search for, is reduced.